# Summing sub arrays (maximal subarray)

Tags: java, complexity

I have this piece of code, and I want to make if the way I'm calculating the time complexity is valid:

```
void traverse() {
    int currSum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < original.length; i++) {
        currSum = original[i];
        for(int j = i + 1; j < original.length; j++) {
            if(max <= currSum) {
                max = currSum;
            }
            currSum += original[j];
        }

        if(max <= currSum) {
            max = currSum;
        }
    }       
}
```

I was thinking it'd be something along the lines of: `(n - 1) + (n - 2) + (n - 3)` ... etc but wasn't sure if that's correct.

Comment: does the code work?

Comment: The complexity is O(n2). If that was your question.

Comment: @Malachi yes, it does

Comment: @Emz do you mean n^2?

Comment: See my answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The complexity of your `void traverse ()` method is `O(n^2)`.

The question is how many times if you have `n`-elements will `currSum += original[j];` be performed.

To calculate that in this case you simply check how many times each loop will be executed.

The outer loop is `n`-times. Based on the `length`. Now the inner loop depends both directly and indirectly on the outer loop. As it will be performed `n` times based on the outer loop and `(n/2)-1` times based on its condition.

So the total time is `(n^2)/2-1` which is written `O(n^2)`.

*If this wasn't your question you should update it to make it more clear.*

*This is not a complete answer. If this satisifies as an answer then it should be moved to Stack Overflow. As it does not have anything to do with reviewing of code.*

---

Some nitpick as well.

```
    if(max <= currSum) {
        max = currSum;
    }
```

Logically you would write it as

```
    if(currSum > max) {
        max = currSum;
    }
```

There is no real need to compare if they are equal and then give a new value (which will be equal to the old) if they are equal.

---

Now for the algorithm itself. If the problem is to find the maximum subarray I suggest you have a read over at [Kadane's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem), as it solves this in `O(n)` instead.

```
public int maxSubArray (int[] a) {  
    int max = 0;
    int cur = 0;
    for (int i : a) {
        max = Math.max (i, max + i);
        cur = Math.max (cur, max);
    }
    return max;
}
```